# Don't kill Activity when pressing back button

Tags: java, android, navigation, android-activity, countdowntimer

I have four activities, ABCD.

The user will initially go ABCD, then the user may want to tap the back button to check something on C before tapping a button on C to take them forward to D again.

The problem I have is that D is running a count down timer which needs to continue counting down and updating on an activity D view. If I currently tap back to go back to C then tap to go forward to D again, the countdown timer is still running but not connected as a new activity has been created for D.

I'd like the user to be able to navigate back to C without it affecting or destroying D so I can keep my timer hooked up to the view.

Finally, if the user clicks back to B, it would destroy both C and D activities (and the countdown timer).

Comment: you should consider creating a service for this kind of operation, or maybe you could store time as the D activity closes into something and on coming back you could compute diferential time

Comment: you can also use Application class to store global data of the timer (like start time and amount of time to measure) and create timer each time you enter the activity using these stored values.

Comment: I'd like the timer to continue running so that I can trigger alarms throughout the countdown at specific times. I'll look in to services, thank you.

Comment: what if you make the timer static? This way you can access and run timer in other activities as well.

Comment: I hadn't considered that, I'll think about how this might work for my app, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quit easy save the timer value and current time on saveInstanceState call back when users leave the activity. When activity recreates use the timer value plus it with (current time - lastSavedTime) and set the timer.

---

it should work just fine but you can achieve this in better way by using fragments and ViewPager.

In case you didn't used ViewPager before. its a component that let you switch between different views by swiping screen to left or right. By default view pager loads the current view and one near it in both side. so if you are in page 1 (index 0) page 1 and page 2 is loaded. if your are in page 2, page 2, page 1, and page 3 will be loaded and so on. The good news is you can change the number of pages that will load near each fragment using simple code like this

```
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
```

So now all 4 fragments are loaded. So you have 4 fragments all loaded on screen. According to developers.android.com all the others views (except one on screen) are loaded but in idle state so I don't think you can have your timer inside fragment D. But that wouldn't be a problem because you only have one activity. Implement your timer in the one and only activity you've got and it will work fine because this activity will not be destroyed when pages change. But you still need to save the same data (timer data + current time) because activity may stop due to user switching to another app.

last thing you need to do is accessing timer data inside your fragment. I will not explain how since there is so many tutorial on how to communicate between activities and fragments but just to give you and idea you need to declare an interface inside your fragment, implement this interface in activity and use this interface inside your fragment to access timer data.

The second solution is a lot more complex but it gives the user a better experience and performance increase is noticeable. Decide witch one is best for you. Good luck

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I may end up implementing this as it would be quite nice for user experience also.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, C.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

to put your D activity to background and then resume it from C like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, D.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

However, you should use a service for this sort of background tasks.

Comment: I've just tried this and pressing back in D takes the user to the home screen instead of C.

Comment: It's now creating a new instance of D again, so the timer is no longer updating the D view.

Comment: You should set the launch mode in manifest to "singleTask" for both activities ( android:launchMode="singleTask" in the activity tag )

Comment: Still not happening, the countdown timer does not connect back up with the view when starting timer on D then going back to C then forward to D again.

Comment: May I suggest you to use a Handler postDelayed(myRunnable, time); instead of Timer ? It is more "Android style"